# MySQL - storing an array of references in each row

Tags: php, mysql

How would I go about storing an array of references in a row? For example, if I were to make an online trading card game, I would have a table with all the cards, and each player would have a deck, represented by a list of ID-references.

Comment: Any time you're tempted to store an array of values in a single column of a database, flashing red lights and klaxons should go off in your head, warning you that your DB design needs to be better normalized.

Comment: @Christopher - you do realize that the problem is in database design, not actually storing language constructs in relational database system?

Comment: @Mickael, I do belive I read the question too quickly and my brain went off on a tangent; my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd make a separate relation table for that, with `card_owner_id` and `card_id` as the fields. Set foreign keys accordingly to automatically delete the relations when a card or user is deleted.

Comment: so would I use something like `SELECT * FROM cards WHERE card_id = (SELECT card_id FROM user_cards WHERE card_owner_id = $user_id)` to get a user's cards?

Comment: You can use a join to get them: `SELECT c.* FROM cards AS c LEFT JOIN user_cards AS uc ON (uc.card_id = c.id AND uc.card_owner_id = $user_id)`.

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions:

1. Serialize your php array and store it into a binary field of your table.
2. Design your database so that you can represent such a relation: "a player has several cards": Player(player_id); Card(card_id, player_id)

Answer (score 0):

How about one table for the players, one for the cards and one for the decks (which links playerId and cardId)?

Answer (score -1):

Each player might have a row in the "players" table; and each of those rows might have a field for each of all the possible cards; and each of those cells might be marked true or false to signify the player's owning or not-owning the card in question.

Would that work, do you think?

-- pete

Comment: Please don't sign off posts on SO.

Comment: I thought about having a fixed deck size and having that many fields in the user table, but that really seemed inefficient.